# understanding the call sequences during RMI

Tags: java, network-programming, rmi, stub

I have many doubts regarding the call sequence during *Remote Method Invocation*.
Following are the 4 error free pieces of code that i read to understand *RMI.*

**1.) INTERFACE**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface AddServerIntf extends Remote {
    double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**2.) IMPLEMENTATION**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class AddServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AddServerIntf {
 public AddServerImpl() throws RemoteException {} // what is it meant for ?

 public double add(double d1 , double d2) throws RemoteException {
      return d1 + d2;
 }
}
```

**3.) AddServer Class**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.*;

  public class AddServer {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        AddServerImpl addServerImpl = new AddServerImpl();
        Naming.rebind("AddServer",addServerImpl); // what does it do and how ?
     }  catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("Exception : " + exc);
       }
   }
  }
```

**4.)AddClient Class**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public class AddClient {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      String addServerURL = "rmi://" + args[0] + "/AddServer";
      AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf)Naming.lookup(addServerURL); // how does it look up and how does it return ?
      System.out.println("The first number is : " + args[1]);
      double d1 = Double.valueOf(args[1]).doubleValue();
      System.out.println("The second number is : " + args[2]);
      double d2 = Double.valueOf(args[2]).doubleValue();
      System.out.println("The sum is : " + addServerIntf.add(d1,d2)); // what does it mean to call the method of an interface ?

    } catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
      }
  }
}
```

**Files on server machine : AddServer.class,AddServerImpl.class,AddServerImpl_Stub.class , AddServerIntf.class**

**Files on client machine : AddServerIntf.class,AddClient.class,AddServerImpl_Stub.class**

After keeping the above files in their respective places,i start the *rmiregistry* on the server machine,then start the server using `java AddServer` and then start the client using `java 127.0.0.1 20 30`

As soon as the client starts what does the statement `(AddServerIntf)Naming.lookup(addServerURL);` in the code `AddClient` do ?

What are the routines that are carried out when the client program starts executing ? How does it return the sum ?

What does the statement `Naming.rebind("AddServer",addServerImpl);` do in the class `AddServer` ?

Finally when i call to fetch the sum using `addServerIntf.add(d1,d2)` , what does it mean (calling the method of interface) ? Why am i calling the method of an interface ? And what does that do ?

I am unable to understand the mechanism of RMI , who calls whom and HOW ?.

Comment: @voterToClose I have asked how is the above code working ? what are the steps that are involved in returning the result w.r.t to the above code ?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the feedback.

Comment: Please let me if my updated response addresses your concerns !

Answer (score -2):

RMI : **Remote Method invocation**.

Generally when we say I invoke a method, we implicitly assume that the method of a class loaded in the same JVM as the invoking class. RMI lets you do the same thing but the calling method and the callee  are in different JVMs (typically on two different physical machine).

In a typical RMI there are two parts:

1. Client : the object which calls
2. Server : The object which entertains the calls of the client.

Before answering your questions one by one, here is how a typical client server communication takes place (high level).

**Server starts up**

- Register the Remote  (`AddServerImpl` ) object to its registry.
- Starts litening to a port (standard 999).

**Client invoking remote method**

- Client queries the server regitery for remote object (`(AddServerIntf)Naming.lookup(addServerURL)`)
- Server returns remote stub (which implements the same interface as the remote object)
- Client calls method on the stub (`addServerIntf.add(d1,d2))`)
- The stub serializes (*converting to a format which could be transmitted over network*) the inputs (`(d1,d2)`), passes them to sever as a request.
- On server side, he input is de-serialized (*recreating java objects from the data received over network*) and  server executes the method on the real object (`AddServerImpl` ).
- The method output (`return d1 + d2`) is returned by method, server serializes the output and sends it as response to calling client
- The stub de-serializes the response and you have output !

Let me answer your questions

*what does the statement `(AddServerIntf)Naming.lookup(addServerURL);` in the code `AddClient` do* ?

--This is the request to the Server to give the remote reference to the object whose method we intent to call.

*What does the statement `Naming.rebind("AddServer",addServerImpl)`; do in the class AddServer ?*

--This is to make sure that server knows (added in its registry) that there is an object with name "AddServer" SO THAT whenever there is a request for invocation of method of this object, it could be served.

*when i call to fetch the sum using addServerIntf.add(d1,d2) , what does it mean (calling the method of interface) ? Why am i calling the method of an interface ? And what does that do ?*

--An interface is a java mechanism to achieve *abstraction*. Now when you call an interface, under the hood, a method of an object implementing the same interface is called (in this case remotely, of the object on server). To answer 'Why', abstraction helps you keep usage and implementation separate. So that the caller need not know the details of implementation () and it should only worry only about the the input and output parameters.

To answer your remaining question

*What are the routines that are carried out when the client program starts executing ? How does it return the sum ?*

--With the background so far, please refer to [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html) . Its has explained in far nicer way than I could :).

Comment: Not very clear and a bit inaccurate. RMI skeletons have been obsolete since 1998. Binding makes the stub available to clents via a named lookup. The sugnimplents the remote interface, so calling the interface means calling the stub, and the stub calls the remote object. 'Why' is because the client doesn't hav the remote object, because it's remote: it has a stub object that implements the same remote interface instead. The link you posted has its problems too, see the correspondence.

Comment: I agree too. And i think skeletons have been obsolete since jdk1.2

Comment: Thanks. I was living in an old era. This is what I like about this site.

Comment: the stub on the client side can both serialize and deserialize the objects ?

Comment: Yes. While requesting serialization and while accepting response de-serialization.

Comment: And 999 is not the standard port. Naming.lookup() is a request to the RMI Registry, not 'the Server'. Binding precedes invocation of remote methods: it isn't part of it. You need to fix this post, or delete it.